# How to deal with an ultra competitive colleague

Tags: colleagues

I have a colleague who is competing for my work, wants to be in all my meetings, even wants my office. I'm finding this very distracting - is it better to give in and let her have what she wants or risk causing conflict by  pushing back?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: If she is actually doing better work, then I don't see what the problem is in her getting better recognition. Maybe I don't really get your question.

Comment: If you can't do better than her, then, she's better than you ... Where is the problem ?

Comment: Some people are willing to take these sacrifices. Do you want her to stop working late? What's really making it unbearable to work with?

Comment: @JMK - People who don't admit to making mistakes are very difficult to work with. They waste time covering their tail, aren't teachable, and make everyone else look bad. I have no time for people like that.

Comment: This question reads more like a rant. [Real Questions have Answers](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2696#2696)

Comment: Thanks for the perspective - harsh but helpful. I wouldn't say she does better work than me she's just more aggressive. I have worked with other equally competent people who were probably smarter than her but we were able to collaborate and respect each other's strengths and areas of responsibility. This one wants everything - my job, her job, my office, the meetings I'm invited to. So either I give in or I push back - either way it's distracting and annoying. I don't think I said she does better work - she's just more aggressive.

Comment: @GoingCrazy Ok, the situation wasn't clear from the initial version of the question, but the comment above and the new version is better and doesn't sound like a rant. I will think over this, and post an answer if I have something.

Comment: Thanks Happy - definitely didn't mean for it to sound like a rant. I think my team is in a stressful situation right now with jobs under threat and it just brings out the worst in everyone ie it makes my colleague overly pushy and me overly sensitive. In the end I spoke to my manager about it so that she's aware of the tension and asked her to be as clear as possible about who's doing what. She appreciated knowing what was going on since she'd noticed a change in behavior too so just knowing that she's aware makes me feel better and less threatened. Thanks to everyone for hearing me out.

Answer (score 2):

If she convinced your bosses and if other people are OK with this, then it's only your problem. You can get used to this, or change job. It sounds like this went on for a while, and you might want to get some fresh air somewhere else. If she's as good as it seems she will either be promoted or headhunted, so she might become your boss or leave the company. In any case, do your best to be professional and try to understand what motivates her, maybe you will learn something and improve your own work in the process.